# MSVSMON over forwarded TCP connection

Tags: tcp, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging, forwarding

I have a server where some code written by me runs. Unfortunately something went wrong and I cannot easily reproduce it on my development machine.

So I want to remote debug it using VS remote debugger. This is normally not a big deal but in this scenario I cannot reach the server directly but only via a second one. So I tried to forward some port (14016 since I cannot not use 4016 directly) to the target machine's port 4016.

When I try to attach to the process running on the target machine VS tells me that the remote debugger seems not to be running on the target machine.

What I see when using Wireshark is that VS sends some data over TCP containing a URI in the form of net.tcp://192.168.172.34:14016/Microsoft/VisualStudio/msvsmon. 192.168.172.34:14016 is the IP and port of the intermediate server which does the port forwarding. This makes sense since VS only knows this server.

The problem seems to be that the MSVSMON checks at least the port number or maybe also the IP and answers with http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2006/05/framing/faults/EndpointNotFound as can be seen in Wireshark...

So the question is: Is there a way to make debugging over a forwarded TCP connection possible?

Answer (score 1):

This may be too late for you. But it may help the googlers out there:

This worked for me in a similar setting. I don't know if some features were broken and I just didn't know about. I could use breakpoints, single-stepping and see variables. Enough for me.

- Add "127.0.0.1 remote-debug" to your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) on the remote machine.
- Add "192.168.172.34 remote-debug" to your hosts file on your dev machine.
- Start msvsmon.exe with "/hostname remote-debug".
- Connect the debugger to "remote-debug:14016"

(Take this as basic idea, you may need to fiddle around a bit. Maybe don't use "/hostname" at all. Maybe use the network IP instead instead of "127.0.0.1".)